# A verb that means making dimples in dough with fingertips

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, food

Is there a verb or baker's term which describes the act of pressing dough with your fingertips to make dimples? Is there a more succinct way of expressing this action?

[image]

Is the term *dimple* the most appropriate?

Comment: To dimple (perhaps) :v.tr.
to produce dimples in. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dimple

Comment: If you prick dough with a fork, that's called "docking." If you use your fingertips, that's called "dimpling. " https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100630123904AAaDDUK

Comment: @Josh61 you know I don't like "answers" in comments. I'm also looking for a sentence with the verb being used.

Comment: @ Io non capisco niente di cucina, anyway : Dimpling means pressing your fingers into the dough to create 'dimples.'  . I thought it was an (too) easy question...or not?http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/30866/when-preparing-focaccia-what-does-dimpling-mean

Comment: @Josh61  I didn't know "dimple" was also a verb! I should have checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dimple](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dimple) v. to mark with or as if with dimples; produce dimples in

---

[A user on a recipe exchange forum asks:](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/30866/when-preparing-focaccia-what-does-dimpling-mean)

> When preparing focaccia, what does "dimpling" mean?

To which the first response is:

> Dimpling means pressing your fingers into the dough to create 'dimples.'

---

Indeed, [this](http://www.italianfoodforever.com/2011/09/how-to-make-focaccia-step-by-step/) focaccia recipe instructs one to (emphasis mine):

> Use the tips of your fingers **to dimple** the entire top of the focaccia.

Comment: Bravo! I very much like the sentence suggested too. I doubt anyone else will come up with something better.

Comment: You may be interested to know that "to dimple" is not a recent "verbing" of the noun.  I've found it in "The Wonders of the Peake" from 1683! https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=udo0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=dimple&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAjgeahUKEwjw9Yie5pHHAhVhj9sKHVJ7CP8#v=onepage&q=dimple&f=false from 1683

Comment: And even earlier, a play acted in 1599, but printed in 1616: "Every Man Out of His Humour", by Ben Jonson. 
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M9k_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA154&dq=dimple&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBTgeahUKEwjw9Yie5pHHAhVhj9sKHVJ7CP8#v=onepage&q=dimple&f=false